# A linguagem de programação Python pode ser usada no front-end?

Tags: python, front-end

A linguagem de programação Python pode ser usada no front-end, junto com HTML?

Caso sim, como faço essa junção entre as duas linguagens?  No meu conhecimento, para chamar um arquivo JavaScript em HTML usar a tag `<script>`. Porém sei que JavaScript é uma linguagem web, então temos todo um suporte, já o Python não. Como podemos fazer essa junção?

Comment: Só se usar Python no _back-end_. Mas se você quiser usar no _front-end_, não é possível não.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta é sim, mas com ressalvas.

Python é uma linguagem de programação como o JavaScript também é. A diferença é que os navegadores possuem [motores JavaScript](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretador_de_JavaScript) nativos. Portanto, nos navegadores que utilizamos hoje, não existe um interpretador ou compilador de código Python.

Mais recentemente, os navegadores passaram a suportar, também, o WebAssembly [(suportado em >96% dos navegadores atuais)](https://caniuse.com/wasm). É uma linguagem de baixo nível análoga ao Assembly. O Python já foi portado para WebAssembly com o projeto open-source [Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide), que permite rodar código Python no navegador diretamente. Veja um exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.3/full/pyodide.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Pyodide test page <br>
    Open your browser console to see Pyodide output
    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function main(){
        let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
        console.log(pyodide.runPython(`
            import sys
            sys.version
        `));
        pyodide.runPython("print(1 + 2)");
      }
      main();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Uma outra forma seria escrever código Python a ser transpilado (compilado + traduzido) para JavaScript. É parecido com o que o TypeScript faz, mas um pouco mais afrontoso. Um projeto que faz isso hoje é o [Skuplt](https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt).